# OAuthWebSecurity cuts server request

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-oauth

I'm trying to make the registration of a social network, but when I send a request via OAuthWebSecurity, AuthenticationResult,IsSuccesful is false.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
  return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}

//
// GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
  AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));

  if (!result.IsSuccessful)
  {
    return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
  }
```

Log4net write:

```
2013-08-22 16:20:16,261 (GMT+6) [27] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Incoming     HTTP request: GET http://localhost/account/externallogincallback?__provider__=google&__sid__=8bcdd01d279e44ef8ecabbf19e689ab7&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2013-08-22T10%3A22%3A02Z-iGxI_3j1iUngw&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3F__provider__%3Dgoogle%26__sid__%3D8bcdd01d279e44ef8ecabbf19e689ab7%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid&openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9Vtl8tOWE1Qt3WZD2701kgGGRxCRoKd7vEqq1gTV5GW1GNs2zOVwyC8a7Dk&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.alias1%2Cext1.value.alias1&openid.sig=JBAcIBr98sjm%2FUHcQLJRXBEqc8c%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkqgxNrvD9N5RuJgh5iIj_VmzThXh3VnY4&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkqgxNrvD9N5RuJgh5iIj_VmzThXh3VnY4&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.alias1=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.alias1=a.k.t%40gmail.com
2013-08-22 16:20:16,291 (GMT+6) [27] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging - Protocol error: The openid.return_to parameter (http://localhost/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=google&__sid__=8bcdd01d279e44ef8ecabbf19e689ab7&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid) does not match the actual URL (http://localhost/account/externallogincallback?__provider__=google&__sid__=8bcdd01d279e44ef8ecabbf19e689ab7&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid&openid.ns=http:%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2013-08-22T10:22:02Z-iGxI_3j1iUngw&openid.return_to=http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3F__provider__%3Dgoogle%26__sid__%3D8bcdd01d279e44ef8ecabbf19e689ab7%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid&openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9Vtl8tOWE1Qt3WZD2701kgGGRxCRoKd7vEqq1gTV5GW1GNs2zOVwyC8a7Dk&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.alias1%2Cext1.value.alias1&openid.sig=JBAcIBr98sjm%2FUHcQLJRXBEqc8c%3D&openid.identity=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkqgxNrvD9N5RuJgh5iIj_VmzThXh3VnY4&openid.claimed_id=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawkqgxNrvD9N5RuJgh5iIj_VmzThXh3VnY4&openid.ns.ext1=http:%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.alias1=http:%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.alias1=a.k.t%40gmail.com) the request was made with.
```

that is, it takes only a part of the request, and so can not authorize. In what could be the problem? 
Thanks in advance